# Can I create an alias that has a param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, controller, generator, alias

I wish to shorten the typing of this:

```
rails g controller --skip-helper --skip-assets --skip-views --skip-template-engine c6
```

where `c6` is the controller name.

I'd like to be able to type `railsgbc c6` # note: gbc=generate basic controller

I've tried:

```
$ alias railsgc='rails g controller --skip-helper --skip-assets --skip-views --skip-template-engine'
```

but then when I try to use it I get:

```
$ railsgc play5
No value provided for required arguments 'name'
```

which is actually the same as if I type:

```
$ rails g controller --skip-helper --skip-assets --skip-views --skip-template-engine c6                                                         
No value provided for required arguments 'name'
```

so it seems that I can't put the argument at the end, it needs to be right after `controller`...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create an alias supporting a parameter. What you can do is to create a function. Adding it to `~/.bashrc` will make it.

For example, to make backups:

```
f_bk () {
        cp -p $1 $1.$(date "+%Y%m%d")
}
```

In your case, if you want to add something after the last word, then this could make it:

```
myrails () {
    rails g controller --skip-helper --skip-assets --skip-views --skip-template-engine $1
}
```

And call it for example with:

```
myrails c8
```

Note that `$1` will be the first parameter, `$2` the second and so on.

Comment: Why create the alias? You can call the function directly.